# connected sum of tori and projective space with some discs removed

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$ with the interior of an embedded disc removed, and let $Y$ be the connected sum of two tori with the interiors of two embedded discs removed. What is $X\#Y$?

(Using the polygonal representation, for $\mathbb{T}\#\mathbb{T}\#\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$ we have the word $aba^{-1}b^{-1}cdc^{-1}d^{-1}ee$, but how are the removed discs represented? And how do I ultimately determine the resulting space?)

Comment: You get $ \mathbb{T}\#\mathbb{T} \#\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2 $ with the interiors of three embedded disks removed, since you can slide around the disks..
 The representation in terms of polygonal representation only works for surfaces without boundaries.

Comment: Ok. Is there any space I can say this is homeomorphic to?

Comment: I am not aware of any particularly interesting homeomorphic surface.

Comment: You can look up the classification of surfaces but I think there is not much more to be said than that this is a connected sum of two tori and a real projective space.